# Dynamics CRM C# SDK - Trying to get name of Quote Line, but field does not exist?

Tags: c#, sdk, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'd like to list out the Quote Lines of a Quote, while keeping the interface generic enough to be able to display other entities similarly.

In order to do this, I'm trying to make use of the PrimaryNameAttribute found in the EntityMetadata.  Works great for most entities, but for QuoteDetail, the PrimaryNameAttribute is "productidname" - an attribute that doesn't actually exist as part of the QuoteDetail entity.

This field, "productidname", is also the PrimaryNameAttribute for other entities (OpportunityProduct, SalesOrderDetail), and in those cases the field is also missing.

What gives?  I feel like I've searched all of Google and it doesn't seem anyone has run into this issue before, so, maybe I'm missing something simple.

Here's the QuoteDetail entity page off of MSDN that shows what I'm talking about:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607959.aspx  Notice that the PrimaryNameAttribute isn't listed anywhere else on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuoteDetail (like SalesOrderDetail and OpportunityProduct) is special in that it can be either relation entity to a Catalog Product item or Write-In item and gets its "name" from either `productidname` (product from catalog) or `productdescription` (write-in product). You will need to JOIN the related Product to get its name.

If you are about to develop a generic solution/interface, this is a problem you need to tackle for every Lookup attribute.

If you only ever need the PrimaryNameAttribute from records connected in Lookups, you can retrieve the name from the `FormattedValues` collection of your "main" entity:

```
string productname = quotedetail.FormattedValues["productid"];
```

yet better/safer:

```
string productname;
quotedetail.FormattedValues.TryGetValue("productid", out productname);
```

Handling attributes of an arbitrary entity can look like this:

```
foreach (var key in record.Attributes.Keys)
{
    if (record.FormattedValues.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        string formattedvalue;

        if (record.FormattedValues.TryGetValue(key, out formattedvalue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(formattedvalue); // use formattedvalue string
        }

        continue; // skip to next field when found in formatted values
    }

    object attributevalue;

    record.Attributes.TryGetValue(key, out attributevalue);

    object actualvalue;
    string actualtext = string.Empty;

    // handle AliasedValue fields from JOINed/LinkEntities
    if (attributevalue.GetType().Name == "AliasedValue")
    {
        actualvalue = ((AliasedValue)attributevalue).Value;
    }
    else
    {
        actualvalue = attributevalue;
    }

    switch (actualvalue.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "EntityReference":
            actualtext = ((EntityReference)actualvalue).Name; // this will catch Lookup values not contained in FormattedValues when you just created them
            break;

        case "DateTime":
            actualtext = string.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ((DateTime)actualvalue).ToLocalTime()); // ... any other dateTime format you'd like
            break;

        case "Guid":
            actualtext = string.Format("{0:D}", actualvalue); // Entity Primary key
            break;

        default:
            actualtext = (string)actualvalue; // anything else
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(actualtext);
}
```

You will still have to take care of newly assigned `OptionSetValue` and `Money` attributes (similar to `EntityReference` ones) because those would usually pulled from `FormattedValues`.

Since this example rather deals with existing crm data, you need to be aware of the pitfall that your entity likely will not include all attributes, so instead of iterating `.Attributes.Keys` you may want to go over a predefined collection of attribute names.

My personal strategy is usually to create a lightweight ORM to map between typed objects and CRM entities but this would not fit your requirement of a generic interface.

---

For cases like yours where it's either this or that attribute I put syntactical sugar to work:

```
string pn = qd.GetAttributeValue<string>("productdesription") ?? (qd.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("productid") ?? new EntityReference { Name = string.Empty }).Name;
```

*Try to get the Write-In product name; if it is null, try to get the Lookup name and if this is null, get an empty string from a fake EntityReference.*

This allows rather friction-less coding and solves the "either this or that attribute" nicely.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Is there something in the metadata that can direct my code to bring in the related entities/fields as required?  Or is this something I'll need to hardcode into my solution to cover offending entities?

Comment: Just saw your update.  Will try that shortly.  Thanks again.

Comment: The update example should give you the general idea. I'll add a full code example of how to extract arbitrary attributes later.

Comment: Looking forward to it!  I'll note, as well, that this is a view I intend to display also for entities that have yet to be posted to CRM.  So FormattedValues will be empty, if I'm not mistaken.  Still, I'm curious to see how you would solve this for a generic case!

Comment: I added the promised example - you may want to post a new, more specific question targeted at entities still to be created. I've got the feeling an answer to this would steer towards separating UI and code.

Comment: Thanks again, Filburt, the code you posted taught me a bunch of things I hadn't seen yet...  But I'm still unclear on how to get a product line's name without hardcoding for the variance between catalog items and write-ins.  If I pulled the name by product ID (as you did in your example), that would only work for catalog items not for write-ins.  So, I'd have to write code specific to product line entities to use one or the other.  This seems wasteful given that the PrimaryNameAttribute exists, and I'm still wondering if I'm missing something...

Comment: You'll have to accept that this special part of MS CRM is part of a legacy where MS devs seemed to take the easiest way to allow write-ins. I hope my example of syntactical sugar can help you there. If you are not used to it: When not dealing with generic access to attributes (like my previous example), always prefer `.GetAttributeValue<T>()` over `entity[attributename]`.

Comment: Thanks, Filburt.  Shame about the lazy CRM devs, but, that bit of code you added is pretty slick.  Much appreciated, this will help.

Comment: If you're interessed: [Entity.GetAttributeValue<T> Explained](http://crmentropy.blogspot.de/2013/08/entitygetattributevalue-explained.html) gives a nice summary.